# SSL certificate available to IIS but cannot be selected for VPN (Win2022 Server)

Tags: windows, remote-access, windows-server-2022

I have installed a wildcard SSL certificate on a Win2022 Server for use for both web (IIS) and VPN authentication. I let Windows choose the appropriate certificate store, but for good measure I installed the certificate also on LocalMachine. Now, Web serving works just fine. However, the certificate does not appear on the Remote Access Server choice and consequently cannot be selected. Worse, the RAS now complains that the default self-signed certificate is not identical to the IIS SSL and refuses to start. My question is: **How can I make the new certificate selectable in the RAS configuration page?**

Comment: What are the certificate usages?

Comment: Proves your identity to a remote computer/
/ Ensures the identity of a remote computer
/ 2.23.140.1.2.1
It's stored under "trusted root certification authority" (Current User)

Comment: It needs to be in the Personal store and have the Server Authentication Enhanced Key Usage (EKU) (OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1) .   https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2018/07/16/always-on-vpn-ssl-certificate-requirements-for-sstp/

Comment: thank you very much for your advice; it's highly appreciated. I have copied the certificate to the Personal Store, and I have added the EKU OID to it and to each certificate in its chain-of-trust. I have then restarted the RAS service. However, I still see only the self-signed cert installed automatically and a "default" which cannot be chosen for some reason (it produces an error). What I am missing? :)

Comment: the info box says: [1]Certificate Policy:
     Policy Identifier=Server Authentication
     [1,1]Policy Qualifier Info:
          Policy Qualifier Id=Root Program Flags
          Qualifier:
               c0

Comment: however, I notice that the entry "Key Usage" (value: "Digital Signature, Key Encipherment (a0)") has an attention sign (yellow triangle with an exclamation mark) on it. Does this mean that something is wrong?

Comment: That's an odd assortment of EKU's considering you only need one that isn't present.

Comment: Dear Greg, thank you - but I don't quite understand. I entered the OID that you kindly specified. Why isn't it present? I thought that the text "Server Authentication" would indicate that it was correctly entered...